# Call DLL function with alias "MAX" in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, dll, xls

I have a function in my DLL with alias "MAX".

Then I try to use it via VBA in my Excel document:

- part of VBA-file:

```
Declare PtrSafe Function MAX_impl Lib "model_64.dll" Alias "MAX" (x As Variant, ByVal idx_f As Integer, out As Variant) As Integer
```

- cell value in Excel-file:

`=MAX(B2:B3, 1)`

But instead of call to my DLL-function I got a call to MAX function from Excel.
Is there a way to specify that call should be performed to DLL? 
Maybe some prefix is possible?

Like:

`=<prefix>.MAX(B2:B3, 1) # call to DLL function`

**Solution which worked for me**: I ended up with this prefix - Module1

So in Excel-file I writes:

```
=Module1.MAX(B2:B3, 1)  # this actually calls my DLL function
```

Comment: Change the name from `MAX` to something else because it's colliding with the built-in Excel formula. Forget about the prefix-dot and just name it `<prefix>MAX`.

Comment: @PeterT Thanks, but actually sometimes I am really need a replacement for Excel built-in function.

Answer (score 1):

From the top of my head, I'd suggest you create a public function in a VBA-Module and then call this from within the Excel-Cell.

Say, you want to Call `=MyMax(...)` in order to use the function from your DLL. Then, you'd need to follow those two simple steps:

---

1. Add a module (if not already present), by using **Insert** ➡️ **Module**
2. *Within this module*, please create a **public** function like so:

   ```
   Public Function MyMax(x As Variant, ByVal idx_f As Integer, out As Variant) As Integer
     MyMax = Max(x, idx_f)
   End Function
   ```

---

This allows you to create function `MyMax` that you'll be able to call from your spreadsheet. This, in turn, just acts as proxy to call the actual function from the DLL and returns it's value to the cell.

**Note:** I've not tested it, but I suppose you're better of aliasing your function with a name i) other than "Max" to avoid confusion with built-in functions and ii) other than your proxy function to avoid confusion with that one, as well.

More detailed instructions on how to create such a user defined function, can be found [here](https://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-User-Defined-Function-in-Microsoft-Excel).